# Why are my redo & undo methods for a textbox wrong?

Tags: c#, undo

Can somebody explain to me what I do incorrectly?

```
private Stack<string> undo = new Stack<string>();
private Stack<string> redo = new Stack<string>();

private void undoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         insert();
    if (textBox1.Text !=null)
    {
        redo.Push(textBox1.Text);

        if (undo.Count != 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = undo.Pop();
        }
    }
}

private void redoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (redo.Count !=0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = redo.Pop();
    }
}

    void insert()
    {
        undo.Push(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

This code doesn't change my textbox..maybe the problem is the way i work witf the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

When do you add items to the undo or the redo stack? You have to add items to the undo stack each time you change its text as well. Otherwise the undo stack will always be empty.

EDIT: It makes no sense that you add the items to the undo stack before you try to undo it. You have to add items to the undo stack in the KeyPress or TextChanged event of the TextBox. Do not just call the `insert` method in `undoToolStripMenuItem_Click`.

Comment: i forget to add one method.sorry

Comment: @user3142035 Editied my post to react to your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should call `insert` method on the `textChanged` event ? you are calling it in `undoToolStripMenuItem_Click` for first time.then your undo stack has one element.Then you are doing this immediately:

```
textBox1.Text = undo.Pop();
```

Here your undo has one element which is current text,and you just replacing your textBox content and your text never changes.